# How to get event when moving recordsets Access form?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have an Access form which uses SQL to populate dropdowns. This SQL is using a value in the form for a combo box cb_Priority, such as:

```
SELECT ProjectPriorities.ProjectPriority FROM ProjectPriorities WHERE (((ProjectPriorities.[mType])=[Forms]![testQuery]![mType].value));
```

In other words, I am using the current recordset to populate a dropdown on the form.

I would like to call the following when a user moves between records (ie which one is currently displayed in the form).

```
Form_testQuery.cb_Priority.Requery
```

This repopulates the form dropdown correctly.

However, I cannot find the event for what I would imagine to be something like

```
Form_RecordsetChange()
Form_RecordsMove()
```

How I trigger this `.Requery` method  to allow it to run each time the userform updates to a different record?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The event you are looking for is: `Form_Current`.

Comment: Thanks. I'm so glad this method was named in such a way which intuitively makes sense...